# Generate multiple CSV files, zip them up and kick off as a download, via Django

Tags: django, csv, download, zip

As a view, I can generate a CSV file and return it to the browser for download. Since CSV files don't support multiple worksheets, I want to generate several CSV files and package them up as a zip file that gets downloaded.

Here is the CSV file view:

```
def user_csv_pull(request):        
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=user_list.csv'

    user_list = User.objects.order_by('-date_joined')

    t = loader.get_template('reporting/user_list.csv')
    c = Context({'user_list': user_list,})

    response.write(t.render(c))

    return response
```

I would need to expand this, to support the 4 or 5 other csv files I want to generate but assuming I have that figured out... How do I push it into a zip? Would I need to write the CSV files to disk and then zip them? I've seen other questions posted here that use `SockIO` which seems like something I could use here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [zipfile module](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) is probably your best choice to create zip files.